# Optical Mouse as encoder

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mouse

Recently I discovered the beauty of the optical mouse as an incremental position encoder.

An optical mouse usually contains one component in which a camera is linked to an image processor linked to an USB interface. The resolution depends on the camera resolution. On the internet it is easy to find back the datasheets of this type of components describing also how to read/write with them.

My problem I first need to solve is how to make sure that an encoder mouse is not seen by the laptop/pc as a pointing device without disabling the USB port to which it is connected. I need to use 2 encoders so that means that 3 usb ports need to be used on my PC (running Windows XP), one for the mouse as pointing device and two for a mouse as encoder.

A second question is how to read/write instructions/data from/to the encoder mouse over an USB port? Could someone send me a link to a tutorial/example in C++?

Thanks very much in advance,

Stefan

Comment: This is not at all clear.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This seems like you are asking to have a lot of code written, not for an answer to a specific question.

Comment: If it was an RS-232 mouse, it would probably be easy to do because there's a simple protocol which lets the OS find a mouse on a serial port (configure the port for 1200 bits/second,7 data bits,1 stop bit,no parity,turn off RTS and DTR, wait out 100(?) ms, turn on RTS and DTR, mouse sends back letter "M" and starts normal operation). Playing a little bit with the wiring you could make sure that Windows doesn't have a chance to discover the mouse when it boots. Then you could program the serial port yourself and use the mouse all to yourself.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: He wants to receive coordinates from a mouse, but he doesn't want Windows to take over the mouse and move the pointer on the screen.

Comment: I want to measure the position of an axis making use of an optical mouse. It is possible to read the change in x and y position with an optical mouse. It is excellent to have already an USB connection but once plugging in the mouse in in the USB port of my PC it is seen as a pointing device on the desktop. First I want to disconnect my encoder mouse from the pointing device on the desktop but I don't know how to do this. Once this is done I want to read/write via the USB port to the encoder mouse. Could someone help me out?Stefan

Comment: Alex, thanks for your comments. Indeed that is what I want to do. RS-232 is rather easy but I want to use USB because I need to connect more devices and work with them. Stefan

Comment: No I am not asking for code, but would like to have contact with people who encountered already such a problem. Via Google I found links to WinUSB but being new to C++ programming this seems rather complex. If someone could point me to a simple demo that would be fine. While experimenting with the Arduino microcontroller I discovered the virtual com port but that was only available when using FTDI components. Is somebody aware of a virtual COM port directly connected to the physical USB interface? Writing/reading from a COM port in matlab/Scilab etc is not that difficult.

Answer (score 5):

The USB mouse microcontroller is probably hardcoded to send USB frames identifying itself as a HID device. In that case there's little hope you can succeed in preventing Windows to use it as a mouse. After all this IS a mouse.

If you are in DIY, you could try to hack the mouse board by unsoldering component/wires and directly control the encoders with your arduino. This way, the Arduino could read the data from the encoder and send it to the PC using its own USB serial port.

See an example there:

http://www.martijnthe.nl/2009/07/interfacing-an-optical-mouse-sensor-to-your-arduino/

For more info on HID device: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class
Excerpt: 
"There are two levels of APIs related to USB HID: the USB level and the operating system level. At the USB level, there is a protocol for devices to announce their capabilities and the operating system to parse the data it gets. The operating system then offers a higher-level view to applications, which do not need to include support for individual devices but for classes of devices. This abstraction layer allows a game to work with any USB controller, for example, even ones created after the game."

Comment: So it is not possible to allow a mouse sending its data but not using the info in Windows as mouse data? In other words it is not possible to use only one mouse really as a mouse in Windows and connecting more? I have no experience with plug and play but I hoped that at least something could be configured at the side of the OS.

Comment: IF you knew how to reprogram the mouse microcontroller you COULD make it send the USB frames you want. But programming an arduino looks a way easier method. The problem is not on Windows side. It is that the mouse is sending frames telling the OS: I'm a MOUSE. This is why you can connect any USB mouse and have the OS plug'n play it :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The links are very useful. An arduino may be a good solution, but I have difficulties accepting the idea that my pc/CPU for most of the time is idle but because things become complex an additional processor need to be added. I will try out what is stated in the above listed URLs in order to collect experience and continue searching. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: It is not possible to use an arduino to hack an optical USB mouse without using a USB Host shield. The Arduino is too slow for communicating with the USB port of the mouse. I had a lot of hope to solve the problem in the way Martijn The has indicated (see link above) but he uses a mouse that connects the image sensor via a simple serial protocol to a controller communicating with the PC over USB. My mice do not have a separate controller. Sensor and controller are one component and what comes out is a series of USB packets.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Raw Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to see if you can pick up on the events that way and block Windows from acting on them.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This is new to me so I need some time to find out more.

Comment: Deanma, without having studied in detail what you suggested, is it possible to write to a device by using the Raw input API? It seems to me just reading data that is sent and deciding whether or not to use it and process it. Stefan

Comment: I don't know, but the name would suggest not. What would you want to write to a mouse?

Comment: I looked up the datasheet of the chip containing the camera/image processor/USB interface. One can send a control string to the chip and get the image data back. That is what I would like to do! I am afraid that I need WinUSB for full access to all USB devices.